# Custom ISO not booting on Flash Drive

Tags: live-usb, iso

I've developed a custom minimal ubuntu distribution (there is a specific reason for this) which I've been able to successfully boot inside of a VM and burn to a CD. However, when I try to use unetbootin (or rufus, or dd, or most anything else) it fails miserably. I get two specific errors

```
stdin: not a typewriter

/init: line3: can't open /dev/sr0: No medium found
```

This ISO was built using casper and squashfs if that helps in anyway. 
I've tried setting the live-media-path=/casper/ but that doesn't seem to help that much. I've tried using isohybrid but that doesn't make a difference either.

Does anyone have a pointer or idea that can help? Is there any additional information that I can provide?

Thanks,
Chris

Comment: Did you create the custom iso file inside an VM? In that case, maybe it is relying on some virtual driver, that belongs to that particular virtual machine (and the software creating it).

Comment: The ISO was created on a bare metal host. However, I may have built the kernel and initrd inside of a chroot container. I'll double check that as that may be causing problems. I'll update after I run some tests. Thanks for the idea.

Comment: Sudodus, I have to say that you are a steely eyed missile man. This ended up being the problem. Building the kernel and initrd in the chroot was mucking everything. When I replaced them with kernels built outside of chroot it worked fine. Thank yo so much for the insight.

Comment: I am glad that I could help you find a solution. Thanks for sharing your solution :-)